# I had to programe a eulerian function in typescript for my calculator. Is the function correct?

Tags: html, typescript, math, calculator, calculation

I had to program a eulerian function in typescript for my calculator. I am just not sure if this is correct. It only gives "0" as a result.
The task was to write a function, which calculates a eulerian number, using the number from the input id="zahl1".
Can anyone tell me if this is correct or how to fix my function?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<label for="zahl1"></label>
<input id="zahl1" type="number" placeholder="Zahl eingeben">
<label for="zahl2"></label>
<input id="zahl2" type="number" placeholder="Zahl eingeben"> <br>
<button id="eulerschBtn" class="btn btn-info">Eulersche Zahl</button>
<p id="ergebnis"></p>
</html>
```

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    const zahl1Input: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("zahl1") as HTMLInputElement;
    const zahl2Input: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("zahl2") as HTMLInputElement;

    const plusBtn = document.getElementById("plusBtn");
    const minusBtn = document.getElementById("minusBtn");
    const multiplyBtn = document.getElementById("multiplyBtn");
    const divideBtn = document.getElementById("divideBtn");
    const areaBtn = document.getElementById("areaBtn");
    const scopeBtn = document.getElementById("scopeBtn");
    const potenzBtn = document.getElementById("potenzBtn");
    const facultyBtn = document.getElementById("facultyBtn");
    const eulerschBtn = document.getElementById("eulerschBtn");

eulerschBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const number1: number = Number(zahl1Input.value);
        const number2: number = Number(zahl2Input.value);

        let result: number = eulersch(number1, number2);

        // display on DOM
        const ergebnisInput = document.getElementById("ergebnis");
        ergebnisInput.innerText = result.toString();
    })

})

function eulersch(n: number, m: number) {
    if (m >= n || n == 0)
        return 0;

    if (m == 0)
        return 1;

    return (n - m) * eulersch(n - 1, m - 1) +
        (m + 1) * eulersch(n - 1, m);
let dp = Array.from(Array(n+1),
        ()=> Array(m+1).fill(0));

    // For each row from 1 to n
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        // For each column from 0 to m
        for (let j = 0; j <= m; j++) {

            // If i is greater than j
            if (i > j) {

                // If j is 0, then make that
                // state as 1.
                if (j == 0)
                    dp[i][j] = 1;

                // basic recurrence relation.
                else
                    dp[i][j] = ((i - j) *
                            dp[i - 1][j - 1]) +
                        ((j + 1) * dp[i - 1][j]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Which inputs do you give for zahl1 and zahl2? Note, that your algorithm gives non zero values only for zahl1 greater than zahl2, not the opposite way around.

Comment: I think I might have fixed the function and added what is missing. Is it correct this way?